# Having multiple separate arrays of data, is there any other more efficient method to merge them into objects?

Tags: arrays, swift, object, iteration

I am trying to populate Json downloaded and populate them into an array of objects.  However, there are some complexity on how the data is structured, how would I be able to populate those arrays into objects efficiently?

The following is the basic structure of the Json Data downloaded from a web service:

```
{
    timestamp: [Date],
    openingStockPrice: [Double],
    closingStockPrice: [Double]
}
```

E.g.

```
{
    timestamp: [2019-01-01, 2019-01-02, 2019-01-03....],
    openingStockPrice: [100.0, 101.0, 95.0, ...],
    closingStockPrice: [101.0, 95.0, 99.5, ...]
}
```

Based on the data structure, there are three separate arrays with data types of dates and double.

Therefore, the first item of each of the arrays belongs to the stock pricing for that particular date.  The second item of each of the arrays belongs to the second day... etc.

Currently, I manage to loop through each of the array and populate the data into objects based on the following structure.

```
Struct StockPrice {
    timestamp: Date, 
    openingStockPrice: Double, 
    closingStockPrice: Double
}

var stockPrice: [StockPrice]
```

I manage to organise the data into array of StockPrice objects by looping through each of the arrays separately.  However, looping through each array does not seem efficient at all as the data set becomes large.

Would any one know, possibly, another way to populate multiple arrays into one array of StockPrice objects (in this scenario)?

Comment: One question is why you have 3 arrays to start with, is your Json message really structured that badly?

Comment: Additional Info : # of items in timestamp, openingStockPrice and closingStockPrice are the same.

Comment: That web service was written by other organization, therefore, I would not have any control over it.  I suspect the data was used for mapping trend lines, guess an array of opening stock price will be easier to map over an array of objects.

Comment: Ok, too bad but I guess the answer below by Joshua is the way to go then.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you do, you would still have to iterate through your multiple arrays because you have to fetch each item. I doubt you can find a O(logN) solution because of the nature of the problem. The best is a O(n)

O(n) solution:

```
var stockPrices = [StockPrice]()

//assuming timeStamps, openingStockPrices, closingStockPrices have the same number of elements
for i in 0 ..< timeStamps.count {
    let timeStamp = timeStamps[i]
    let openingStockPrice = openingStockPrice[i]
    let closingStockPrice = closingStockPrice[i]
    let stockPrice = StockPrice(timeStamp, openingStockPrice, closingStockPrice)
    stockPrices(add: stockPrice)
}
```

tbf, an O(n) is relatively fast

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  Guess this seems to be the only feasible method...